# How to setup directory permission in joomla installation

Tags: php, linux, joomla, permissions

I have just unzipped joomla zip contents in `/var/www/site1`

In the joomla backend system info where it says directory permissions there i see all as unwritable.

I want to know that what permission should i give on those folders

1. writable by user
2. writable by apache
3. world writable

Answer (score 1):

All the folders should be 755 & the files should be 644

To recursively give directories read&execute privileges:

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

To recursively give files read privileges:

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced)

Answer (score 0):

Making folder **777** is ***not*** recommended at all and poses security threats.

All folders should be **755** and files should be **644**